# How do I reference another project in a Unity C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

Hi I have some C# code in a .NET class library that I wrote a while back.  If I want to reference that code in a Unity script (Unity 2018.4.19f1 if that matters), how do I go about that?

If I add a project reference to my Unity Assembly-CSharp project in Visual Studio, it doesn't seem to work.  I get;

> Script.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'other-project-namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Does the class .NET class library need to be target a particular framework/platform?  Ideally I'd like to use the same library across platforms if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to build it, then it gave you a DLL file
import that in unity and use it

Comment: I did that, I built my class library, lets say it's called other-project.dll, and referenced that from Assembly-CSharp, is that what you mean by DLL file import?